# Cannot Initialize the reindexer process?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, reindex, theme-fallback

I have uploaded the folders of a new theme into the root folder of magento and then when i am trying to re-index all  the files it is showing :

> cannot initialize the re-indexer process.

I have refreshed all cache but its still not working. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: These folders, you have copied theme via FTP with the same name folders and to the correct path ?

Comment: Check for logs you may find errors there

Comment: Yes @prince i have not overwrite any of the folder just added the folders which were no present there, from theme

Comment: @AmanAlam Where should i check the log and for what errror ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Look the `var/log` for errors.

2) Try to reindex with **SSH** like this :

**Individual re-indexing:**

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat

php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product

php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

**All re-indexing:**

```
 php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Then clear the magento cache.

Comment: You are welcome, if everything is fine, thanks to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Look the `var/locks` for any locks is there.

2) Remove all the locks files (`*.locks`)

3) Try to reindex with SSH from the Magento root like this:

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Then clear the magento cache.